# LWC jest mock custom permission: jest.mock( "@salesforce/customPermission/my-custom-permission",

Tags: lwc-jest, custom-permission, mock

I am mocking custom permission successfully like this:

```javascript
jest.mock(
    "@salesforce/customPermission/my-custom-permission",
    () => {
        return {
            default: true
        }; 
    },
    { virtual: true }
);
```

In another test of the same component I would like to change return value of this mock or clear only this mock. I have tried to `mockReturnValue`, `mockImplementation` and everything I could find from the documentations. Does anyone have an idea how this could be solved?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The lwc-recipes shows using *different* test classes to test different values of the imported permission. It [shows](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/miscPermissionBasedUI/__tests__)

- [miscPermissionBasedUI.negative.test.js](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/miscPermissionBasedUI/__tests__/miscPermissionBasedUI.negative.test.js)
- [miscPermissionBasedUI.test.js](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/miscPermissionBasedUI/__tests__/miscPermissionBasedUI.test.js)

Where the negative version sets the mocked import to return `false`.

```js
jest.mock(
    '@salesforce/customPermission/accessRestrictedUIPermission',
    () => ({
        __esModule: true,
        default: false
    }),
    { virtual: true }
);
```

and the other test sets it to `true`.

```js
jest.mock(
    '@salesforce/customPermission/accessRestrictedUIPermission',
    () => ({
        __esModule: true,
        default: true
    }),
    { virtual: true }
);
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work - that is I couldn't change the response from the mocked imported module after it had first being initialised.  All I could do was split the test into two distinct files and initialise each with default: true or default: false based on which I was testing.  It's worth noting that this is what the recipe repo now does since this Pull Request: https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/pull/774/files

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I updated the answer to match with the recipe change.